# How do I fix this Error 1 when trying to run Site Inspector with Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

Have cloned the Site Inspector repo from Github (https://github.com/siteinspector/siteinspector)

Using Microsoft PowerShell:

```
git clone https://github.com/siteinspector/siteinspector.git

cd siteinspector

docker-compose up
```

The redis, postgres and app images are loaded into Docker fine, but when I run the container on localHost (808), the container exits with a code: 1.

```
Exit Code 1 means that a container terminated, typically due to an application error or an invalid reference.
```

Logs as follows:

```
siteinspector-app-1       | rake aborted!
siteinspector-app-1       | ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit`
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:581:in `validate_secret_key_base'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:419:in `secret_key_base'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:24:in `key_exists?'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:16:in `find'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.8.1/lib/devise/rails.rb:37:in `block in <class:Engine>'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
siteinspector-app-1       | /opt/siteinspector/config/environment.rb:7:in `<main>'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:348:in `require_environment!'
siteinspector-app-1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/application.rb:511:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
siteinspector-app-1       | Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
siteinspector-app-1       | (See full trace by running task with --trace)
siteinspector-app-1 exited with code 1
```

I expected Site Inspector to open on the localhost port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please assign a value to the `SECRET_KEY_BASE` variable in the docker-compose.yml file.

## Here is an example:

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE: 'inputyourkey' # <-- input a key
```

## app example:

```yaml
#docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
      - 'redis'
    image: 'siteinspector/siteinspector:latest'
    ports:
      - '808:808'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    command:  bash -c "rake db:migrate && foreman start"
    environment:
      SECRET_KEY_BASE: 'inputyourkey' # <-- you input a key
      RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: 'true'
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/siteinspector
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
      PORT: 808
      SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY: 10

# ... pass
```

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, you can give me a `useful answer`. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. 

Can this key be any value? Otherwise where do I find the SECRET_KEY_BASE value?

Comment: Yes, you can use any value for the `SECRET_KEY_BASE`. It can be a `random` string.

Comment: You can use websites like https://randomkeygen.com/ for generating random keys.

Comment: I am still getting the same error I'm afraid. I've done as you've suggested and generated a random key (E.g 'CF55FCE32442E') and changed the docker-compose.yml file. 

Then I've tried to run bin/rails credentials:edit but I have no idea what to do with that file. It only contains: 

#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'

---

Comment: How do you execute/run it? Please provide me with the main content or the context of the Docker Compose file.

Comment: You can click on this link to view my file.
https://gist.github.com/CHunYenc/a6e6d691b509837b7fab7456d2c4e0b1
After, run `docker compose up`.

Comment: Figured it out --  rails secret keys need to be 30+ characters long I found. 

Changed in docker-compose.yml and config/secrets.yml files. Removed the old images and containers from docker, then ran docker-compose up again and it worked. 

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Okay, congratulations.
Because your question is about `docker-compose.yaml` missing `SECRET_KEY_BASE`, can you choose me as the best answer?

This is the greatest encouragement for me XD